# How to call a function on checking a checkbox in angular 2.0

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently using angular 2.0. In HTML, I have a checkbox, the code is as mentioned below.

```
<div style="margin-left:15px;">
            <label>Draw</label>
            <input id="isCheckBox" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
</div>
```

How to call a function only if a checkbox is checked in typescript file?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can do this,

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="isCheckBox" (change)="yourfunc($event)"/>
```

and in typescript,

```
yourfunc(e) {
   if(e.target.checked){        
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I use the same thing, but I got this error : "Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined"

Comment: @SoukainaElHayouni Make the code as below, it will work.

yourfunc(e) {
   if(e.checked){        
   }
}


please remove the target property from the code.It worked for me.

Comment: @ADARSHK Thank you for your reply! I solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use currentTarget if target won't work,

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="isCheckBox" (change)="yourfunc($event)"/>
```

and in typescript,

```
yourfunc(e) {
   if(e.currentTarget.checked){        
   }
}
```